# How to insert string at stringbuider at perticular line?

Tags: c#, oop, stringbuilder

I have following code.

```
Dataset function1 (){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('abcd');
sb.append('efgh');
for(int i=0 ; i< 8; i++){
    sb.append('ijkl');
    sb.append('monop');
    sb.append('ijkl');
    sb.append('monop');

}
Dataset ds = function2(sb);
if(ds.isempty(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('abcd');
    sb.append('efgh');
    for(int i=0 ; i< 8; i++){
        sb.append('ijkl');
        sb.append('monop');
        sb.append('ijkl');
        sb.append('464sdfsdfsdfggfdkjkjkjkj');
        sb.append('monop');

    }
    ds = function2(sb);

})
return ds;
```

}

I dont want to rewrite same code in ds.empty() brackets.
Is there any better way to handle this ?

Comment: Why not using `List<StringBuilder> lines`? then if you want *k-th* like it's an easy `lines[k]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET StringBuilder preappend a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861366/net-stringbuilder-preappend-a-line)

Comment: what are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Just put the code in an own method:

```
public StringBuilder GetString(boolean p_appendExtraStrings)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('abcd');
    sb.append('efgh');
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++)
    {
        sb.append('ijkl');
        sb.append('monop');
        sb.append('ijkl');
        if(p_appendExtraStrings)
        {
           sb.append('464sdfsdfsdfggfdkjkjkjkj');
           sb.append('monop');
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

And then you can replace your current StringBuilder code by a call of this method

```
Dataset function1()
{
   Dataset ds = function2(GetString(false));
   if(ds.isEmpty()
   {
      ds = function2(GetString(true));
   }
   return ds;
}
```

Comment: I would work if both string builders were same but if ds is empty , I'm writing same code with extra string appended ( sb.append('464sdfsdfsdfggfdkjkjkjkj'); ) and passing this new string builder to function2.

Comment: Ah i see, my fault. I've updated my code with an extra parameter "p_appendExtraStrings". The extra values will be only appended if the boolean is true. So the first call is with "false" and the second with "true". I hope this correcture will solve your problem!

Comment: It will work fine but still GetString() function is called 2 times. Time complexity is the same as previous code. Is there another method so that time complexity can be reduced ?

Comment: You wrote "I dont want to rewrite same code in ds.empty() brackets" -> So the solution is to put the code in an own method